# Visual Studio 2012 updates

Tags: visual-studio-2012

How can I find What Update version I have in Visual Studio 2012? (update 1 or 2 or 3). HOw can I go back to update 1 so that I can build .dll which can be supported in windows XP? I am sorry It's not a programming question but highly appreciated for your answer. I'm stuck!

I have a following Error: Unable to load DLL 'xxx.dll': The specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F)

My Target OS is windows XP: 32 bit .NET 4.0. 
Also Same dll works for windows 7 and other so I think there shouldn't be dependency problem.

Comment: Don't worry, you're on topic according to the instructions: questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" are OK.

Comment: make sure that the target framework is 4.0 or below.

Comment: To help you debug this problem, we'd need to know the exact error you're experiencing.  Please be sure to turn on Fusion log before reporting the error.

Answer (score 3):

Help -> About will tell you what update you are running.

As far as I can tell, targeting windows XP is supported from VS 2012 with any update.  You just need to make sure the project [targets a version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb398197.aspx) of the .NET framework that is supported on Windows XP. (.NET 4 or earlier)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have an application running on XP which uses .NET 4 and that is fine. But that application is not able to load .dll and eventually it crashes saying System.dllNotFound Exception: Unable to load DLL! This DLL doesn't require .NET framework!

Comment: I got the framework version for running XP wrong, I've now corrected my answer.
@LettuceTomatoOnion - I'm not sure I follow you.  What app? What dll? I think we have all assumed you are using c# or vb and that this is a managed application.  If this isn't the case then could you update your question to better explain your problem please?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I find What Update version I have in Visual Studio 2012?

Open Visual Studio, Click Help, Click About. See Second line.

Mine says "Version 11.0.60315.01 **Update 2**"

> How can I go back to update 1?

(assuming Windows 7)

Control panel > Programs and Features > view installed updates > uninstall the update you want under the Visual Studio 2012 category.

---

That being said, I have no idea if this solution is actually something you need to do or will fix your problem. It is simply about how to remove the updates. It sounds like you may just need to download the latest .NET framework for XP.

Comment: Let me try to do that! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have set target 4.0 and also I have updated .NET support for 4.0 on XP.

Comment: @LettuceTomatoOnion and it still won't load your DLL?

Comment: Yes, it is still unable to load .DLL

Comment: To be honest, it sounds like it just can't find the dll. Can you double check the path of the dll that you are loading? If it was unable to load it, it would usually say something like `Bad Format Exception` or something else. Not "can't find the dll".

Comment: I have a following Error: Unable to load DLL 'xxx.dll': The specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F)